# How to get instagramAPI access code in Django

Tags: django, instagram-api

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how do i get an access code from Instagram in Django? I am stuck the bold portion below:

Server-side flow (recommended):Redirect the user to a URI of your choice. Take the provided code parameter and ***exchange it for an access_token by POSTing the code to our access_token url.***

```
clientID = '*******************'
clientSecret = '****************'

def index(request):
    if request.GET:
        code = request.GET['code']
        url  = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"
        settings = { 'id'        : clientID,
                     'secret'    : clientSecret,
                     'grant_typ' : 'authorization_code',
                     'redirect'  : 'http://localhost:8000/User',
                     'code'      : code  
                     }
        #return something
    else:
        return render_to_response('User/index.html')
```